# CA2242 Test for Nan correctly

Tags: c#, performance, silverlight, code-analysis

I tried to write code by help Code Analysis. Here is my problem. Code Analysis show me CA2242 on the line started by 'if'. How can I fix that? I applied modification from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CA2242%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-Silverlight) but without successfull.

```
if (!Double.IsNaN(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth))
                dlgWait.Width =  Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
```

**EDIT**:
See picture [image]

Comment: This looks okay for me, Are you sure error is in this line? or some other place?

Comment: Looks fine to me; random thought - is it any happier with `double.IsNan` ? (case)

Comment: I am sure, that is on this line. I tried ternary operator and if statement.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think problem is in code analyzer in Microsoft Visual Studio. I add suppressMessage to hide warning, but it is not finally solutions. If anyone want know how to resolve, please let me know.

```
 [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2242:TestForNaNCorrectly")]
```